# Is "stemmed to" ok, and what does it mean?

Tags: grammar

Consider this:

Poverty and substandard infrastructure are present in almost every place in the India, especially New Delhi, its capital. Having been left unattended for decades, these problems have **stemmed to** more serious setbacks today such as pollution and illiteracy.

Comment: A more appropriate question is 'Is "stemmed to" correct in this sentence?' Famously, "Colorless green ideas sleep furiously" has impeccable grammar.

Comment: The writer apparently thought there was a reverse form of "stem from" ("stem to").  This is not the case.  As other commenters pointed out,  _lead to_ or _cause_  are more apt expressions of this concept.

Answer (score 2):

The writer of the original quote is probably not entirely proficient in English. He (or she) was probably thinking along the lines of "the problems of illiteracy and pollution stem from the long-ignored conditions of poverty and substandard infrastructure".

Unless, of course, Indian English has recently taken up the phrase "stem(med) to".

Comment: If we replace "stemmed to" with "resulted in" or "led to", would the sentence be grammatically correct? Do you see other mistakes aside from "stemmed to"?

Comment: I think your alternatives are just fine.

Comment: +1. This must be it. And I've never seen 'stem to' being used for anything in InE

Answer (score 0):

"Stemmed to" is grammatically correct, but probably does not express the desired meaning. I suspect that "caused" or "resulted in" better express the intended meaning, since the understood subject of the second sentence is the causes, Poverty and substandard infrastructure. If the subject of the second half were the consequences, pollution and illiteracy, i.e.

> Pollution and illiteracy stem from poverty and substandard infrastructure, which are present in almost every place in the India, especially New Delhi, its capital, and which have been left unattended for decades.

Answer (score 0):

As brasshat indicates, the original quote is probably confusing things:

**This *results in* that**  (this causes that)

**This *stems from* that**  (that causes this)

**This *leads to* that** (this causes that)